# st_clip and gdal_translate: "Error browsing database for PostGIS Raster properties" - Why?

Tags: postgis, gdal, postgresql, shell

I'm using shell-script, PostGIS 2.0 and GDAL for trying to clip raster apart, using an overlapping raster and a the_geom-object. At first I create a view to clip the overlapping part of the raster. It gives me several raster-tiles as results, which I bundle with st_union as one raster. It works all fine and I can see results in the tables.

```
psql -h localhost -p 5432 -d testlauf -U postgres <<EOF
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW profilschnitt.cliptest AS
SELECT st_union(st_clip(a.rast, b.the_geom))
FROM rastertable a
JOIN tiletable b
ON (st_envelope(a.rast) && b.the_geom);
EOF
```

Now I want to see how the unified raster looks in GIS and try to export the raster via gdal_translate into SAGA-rasterformat:

`gdal_translate -ot Float32 -of SAGA PG:"host=localhost port=5432 dbname=testlauf user=postgres password=postgresdb schema=profilschnitt table=cliptest mode=2" ~/Desktop/cliptest.sdat`

Problem is, that GDAL tells me the following:

> ERROR 1: Error browsing database for PostGIS Raster properties
>   GDALOpen failed - 1

My db-connection is set up correctly and gdal-translate already worked with other raster-views/-tables too. So I assume that the problem must be somewhere within the query-view...

Answer (score 3):

Okay, i found my mistake: it seems helpful to create a, additional column "rid" in the view. Now export works fine. I added the correct query:

`psql -h localhost -p 5432 -d testlauf -U postgres <<EOF CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW profilschnitt.cliptest AS SELECT 1 as rid, st_union(st_clip(a.rast, b.the_geom)) FROM rastertable a JOIN tiletable b ON (st_envelope(a.rast) && b.the_geom); EOF`

Regards,
knutella