# How to export raster from PostGIS enabled DB as GTiff with gdal_translate

Tags: postgis, raster, gdal, export, gdal-translate

When I want to export a GTiff from my PostGIS DB with this code:

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff PG":host='localhost' port:'5432' dbname='landslide' user='postgres' password='pass' schema='public' table='dgm' mode='2'" test.tiff
```

I get the following error:

```
Illegal filename. character <'> not allowed.Illegal filename. character <'> not allowed.ERROR 4: `PG:host='localhost' port:'5432' dbname='landslide' user='postgres' password='pass' schema='public' table='dgm' mode='2'' does not exist in the file system, and is not recognised as a supported dataset name.

GDALOpen failed - 4 `PG:host='localhost' port:'5432' dbname='landslide' user='postgres' password='pass' schema='public' table='dgm' mode='2'' does not exist in the file system, and is not recognised as a supported dataset name.
```

I followed the [instructions](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/frmts_wtkraster.html) from gdal.

Is the syntax incorrect? I tried to change the quotes, but no success.

Comment: I am trying to do a lo_export of a raster file in postgis, and finally came to SELECT lo_export(oid,'filesystempath');
But When I check the filesystem there is nothing there... anybody knows why? and how can I get it create the TIF file?

Comment: Post this as a question, not as an answer

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/136851)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest you to use this alternative way to do the same:

1. To export raster as TIFF, export it to a lob(large object) and return it’s oid using the query:

   ```
   SELECT oid, lowrite(lo_open(oid, 131072), tiff) As num_bytes
   FROM
   ( VALUES (lo_create(0),
   ST_Astiff( (SELECT rast FROM raster_table WHERE rid = 1) )
   ) ) As v(oid,tiff);
   ```
2. Use the PostgreSQL \lo_export command to output your raster as a tiff file:

   ```
   \lo_export 147303 '/tmp/myraster.tiff'
   ```
3. As you probably don't use the lob anymore you should probably unlink (remove) it by calling:

   ```
   SELECT lo_unlink(147303);
   ```

Later you can GeoReference it using gdal_translate:

```
gdal_translate /tmp/myraster.tiff -of GTiff -a_srs 'PROJCS[AUTHORITY["EPSG","900913"]]' -a_nodata 0 /tmp/myrastergeo.tiff
```

Source: [How to: Create a Heatmap Raster in PostGIS and Render in GeoServer](http://technobytz.com/create-raster-postgis-geoserver-tutorial.html)

Answer (score 3):

Because `-of GTiff` and the quotes may be omitted (there aren't spaces), and double quotes after `PG` usually goes **after the colon** (like stated [here](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_pg.html)), it should be:

```
gdal_translate PG:"host=localhost port:5432 dbname=landslide user=postgres password=pass schema=public table=dgm mode=2" test.tiff
```

Comment: The same error occurs when I try your code.

Comment: And what happens with `gdalinfo`? Same error?

Comment: Yes, same error. Could be something wrong with the raster table?

Comment: Can you load your PG raster table in QGIS using the same parameters?

Comment: This is another problem. I don't know how to load the raster in QGIS (I'm using 2.0). In the PostGIS Layer list is a raster columns entry, but I don't know how to us it.

Comment: It seems that it's possible to load them only in QGIS 1.8: http://libregis.org/2013/07/23/gdal-postgis-raster-driver-ready-for-data-visualization/ The QGIS PostGIS Raster Plugin is not updated yet, sorry. However, the latest improvements of GDAL PostGIS Raster driver should be available in GDAL 1.10.1, released 2013/08/26. What version of GDAL are you using?

Comment: As afalciano said, you can't use QGIS 2.0 yet. I didn't port the plugin to QGIS 2.0. I want to do it before the end of this year. And yes, you should use the last version of GDAL from trunk. It contains some improvements to PostGIS Raster driver.

Comment: This answer does not work

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you wrote

```
PG":
```

And you should write

```
PG:"
```

But you can avoid single quotes too. They shouldn't be necessary.

By the way, I'm the developer of the driver. I strongly recommend you to use the last GDAL version from trunk. It includes some great improvements that make the raster fast enough for data visualization in QGIS or MapServer (I'm actually interested in testing that and get feedback).

Comment: So the [GDAL PostGIS Raster driver documentation](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/frmts_wtkraster.html#a3.2-Readingrasterdatafromthedatabase) needs to be updated accordingly to the [PostgreSQL / PostGIS driver](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_pg.html). This led Stefan (and probably others) to a wrong connection string.

Comment: OMG, absolutely. I've just fixed it. That was a silly and annoying mistake. Sorry for that.

Comment: I installed gdal 1.9.0-3 for linux. But `gdal_translate --version` shows me `GDAL 1.6.0dev, FWTools 2.0.6, released 2008/02/03`. I used 1.6 before. How can get rid of the old version?

Comment: 'gdal-config --prefix' tells you the PATH where default GDAL library (1.6 in your case) is installed. Probably, $HOME/FWTools. You can get rid of that folder. Once done, the default GDAL should be 1.9. You may need to update your PATH variable, to ensure it doesn't contain references to the deleted FWTools folder.

Comment: Do I have to use FWTools again in addition to the newer GDAL? Exporting database data as a shapefile with ogr2ogr doesn't work for me without FWTools. And pgsql2shp shortens the attribute fields to a ten string when I want export data (and especially with queries).

Comment: You don't need FWTools to use ogr2ogr if you compiled GDAL. It's included. You may need to add the path where the new GDAL installed the binaries (gdalinfo, gdal_translate, ogr2ogr...) to system path, if your problem is those commands are not found. About pgsql2shp, is not related with GDAL, and as long as I know, it's not packed with FWTools. It's a PostGIS tool. Which version of PostGIS are you using?

Comment: Sure, psql2shp is a PostGIS tool, but I don't use it because of the known attribute field problem. Selecting PostGIS version gives me:`POSTGIS="2.1.0rc2 r11726" GEOS="3.4.0-CAPI-1.8.0 r3874" PROJ="Rel. 4.7.1, 23 September 2009" GDAL="GDAL 1.9.0, released 2011/12/29" LIBXML="2.9.0" LIBJSON="UNKNOWN" TOPOLOGY RASTER`

Comment: Ok. So, you stick with ogr2ogr. If you installed GDAL properly (and looks that you did, because PostGIS found it), ogr2ogr is installed. Probably at /usr/local/bin. Check if that path is added to your system's path. And ensure where ogr2ogr is with: sudo find / -name ogr2ogr

Answer (score 1):

gdal_translate needs field called rid. So, we must have rid field.
Check this at:

[st_clip and gdal_translate: "Error browsing database for PostGIS Raster properties" - Why?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53964/st-clip-and-gdal-translate-error-browsing-database-for-postgis-raster-properti)

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old question.  The question and answers came up when I was searching for a solution to a similar problem.  All the examples using raster2pgsql or gdal show single quotes around the database table or especially the column name.  The desire is to keep the column name lower cased. Both the table creation and the load of the data was without error using single quotes.  The symptoms of the problem developed when I tried to view the data with QGIS = nothing, or gdalinfo the data = errors.  What happened is that the single quoted rast column name became 'rast' in the database.  At that point, even if you use afalciano's answer of

```
gdal_translate PG:"host=localhost port:5432 dbname=landslide user=postgres password=pass schema=public table=dgm mode=2" test.tiff
```

to read the loaded data, the damage has been done.  You need to rename the column from say 'rast' to rast in the database. The generated constraint names did not matter. After the rename sans the quotes, QGIS version 2.4.0-Chugiak displayed the data and the gdal tools stopped failing and provided me with the desired information.

Comment: I have used following in QGIS 2.18.11 (64 bit). The only difference is use of column = rast inside PG:
  
  

> gdal_translate PG:"dbname=ecolservicedb host=localhost
> user=ecolservice password=ecolservice port=5432 mode=2 schema=public
> **column=rast** table=_ags_473038164" test.tiff

Answer (score 0):

I tested this successfully:

gdal_translate -of PNG  PG:"host='localhost' port='5432' dbname='postgis_db' user='postgres' schema='someschema' table='some_table' mode='2' where='rid=1'" pngfile.png