# Export each raster in a PostGIS raster table as a separate image using gdal_translate

Tags: gdal-translate, postgis-raster

I read from this [SO question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78086) that one can export an entire PostGIS raster table into one image, as follows:

```
gdal_translate PG:"host=localhost port=5432 dbname=landslide user=postgres password=pass schema=public table=dgm mode=2" test.tiff
```

However, my raster table contains many images, one per row. I wanted to export them as such. I see in the documentation that this corresponds to `mode=1`:

> mode - option is used to know the expected arrangement of the raster
> table. There are 2 possible values
>
> mode=1 - ONE_RASTER_PER_ROW mode. In this case, a raster table is
> considered as a bunch of different raster files. This mode is intended
> for raster tables storing different raster files. It's the default
> mode if you don't provide this field in connection string.

But this does not work apparently. If I just change the connection string above to PG:"... mode=1 ...", I get only one output image called `test.tiff` (containing the image on the first row of my table). The rest is missing. I guess that specifying only one output when there are an unknown number of outputs. So, I also tried removing `test.tiff` from the commandline, hoping that the file names will be somehow generated. But gdal_translate says it's invalid usage. I also searched, but couldn't find an example usage of exporting pgraster with `mode=1`.

How can I use `gdal_translate` to export pgraster images in `ONE_RASTER_PER_ROW` mode?